# Points on circumsphere of n-simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Project an n-simplex of side length $a$ on it's ($n-1$)-dimensional circumsphere by a ray starting at the center. Denote the images of the $n+1$ faces of dimension $n-1$ of the simplex by $A_1,\dots A_{n+1}$. Choose $a_i\in A_i, i=1,\dots, n+1$. Are there always $i, j\in \mathbb{N}$ with $d(a_i, a_j)>=a$?

Comment: what is your last $a$?

Comment: its the side length of the inscribed n-simplex

Comment: I assume "midpoint" is the center of the sphere?

Answer (score 9):

**NO**

For a regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb E^3$, if you take a centroid of one face
together with the midpoints of its three edges projected to the circumscribed sphere,
they satisfy your conditions (or if you want the conditions to be strict, each
midpoint of an edge can be perturbed into the adjoining face). The distances are shorter
than the edgelengths of the tetrahedron.  This is geometrically self-evident,
but if you want numbers, for the unit sphere, the edgelengths of the inscribed
regular tetrahedron are $1.63299...$, and the edgelengths for the tetrahedron of the $a_i$
described above are $1.41421...$ and $.919402...$.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5390048/TetrahedronPoints.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5390048/TetrahedronPoints.jpg)